# Fragment basics

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a application for which I have some issues with fragments. First of all , I want to know if it is possible to make one fragment inside another fragment. And the second one is when to call onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() and which is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot create a fragment inside another fragment. You should communicate between fragments thru activity.See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity
2. I didn't understand your second question clearly. But I generally leave onActivityCreated() blank without changing it. And use onCreateView() in a similar way with onCreate().

Comment: A warm thanks to you barisemreefe and sorry if I was not clear what I want to ask. Basically in second question I was asking that what is the difference between these two methods? If we can use anyone then their should be only one method. Why the need of other-one?

Comment: Actually idk what's the difference :) But probably they're similar in many ways but creation time of the components differs.in onActivityCreated components are created when parent activity created. and in onCreateView components are created when fragment is called . Just guessing :D

Comment: Ya me too... Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Android sources:
 `onCreateView` is called by the Activity during the construction of the view hierarchy. This is where the Fragment has the opportunity to instantiate its own user interface view.
 `onActivityCreated` is called when the Activity has been fully created and finished instantiating the view hierarchy.  At this point it's safe for the Fragment to access the its views and restore itself from some saved state.